# Use of Leaflet to display raster image from WMS GeoServer

Tags: raster, leaflet, javascript, wms

I'm trying to display raster images from GeoServer on a Leaflet map.
Simply like this:

```
var map = L.map("mapid").setView([15.6261, -61.44361], 13);
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?', {
    layers: 'geo:africa'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Once the web page is open, the map `div` is totally grayed out.

In the network section of `inspect page` the WMS request to GeoServer is composed of `bbox`, `srs` and other data which are all wrong for the layer being requested:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=geo:xxx&styles=&format=image/jpeg&trasparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG:3857&bbox=-6834081.824921039,1751325.19206996,-6829189.855110788,1756217.1618802093
```

While the request should have these parameters (taken from GeoServer):

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geo/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=geo:xxx&bbox=-30.0044643,-40.00446437384,65.00446439304,40.0044643&width=768&height=646&srs=EPSG:4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers
```

The screen appears as follows:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/417318/edit) the question and add info about all wrong WMS request and how should all right request look like.

Comment: I changed it by adding the missing information @TomazicM

Answer (score 0):

Your map is using EPSG:3857 (the default for Leaflet) and thus requests data using that same CRS from the WMS.

Enable serving images in EPSG:3857 for your WMS and it should work.

Comment: The result does not change even if i add a new Gridset in GeoServer with EPSG:3857

Comment: try zooming out - you may be looking off the edge of your data

Comment: Layer name suggest your map is of Africa, but view center coordinates `[15.6261, -61.44361]` (lat, lng) are SE of Dominica island, above South America.

Comment: I don't know why but it took a long time to load the image on the map, so even when I zoomed out I couldn't see it, thanks.
But how does the transformation of the projection take place? The request to the GeoServer is always with EPSG:3857, but the native srs of the image is EPSG:4326